# VIM automatic indent of LaTeX files bad

Tags: latex, indentation

I want to indent with `gg=G` some LaTeX files. But I get a bad indent.

```
\title{                                                                         
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[0.5em] \huge                                           
\textsc{My headline           
\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}                                                         
}
```

What I get:

```
\title{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[0.5em] \huge
        \textsc{My headline
            \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
}
```

What I want (or similar):

```
\title{
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}\\[0.5em] \huge
    \textsc{My headline
    \rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
}
```

Is this normal? Wrong config file? Flags? AddOns? Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: The indent wich you are getting with vim is correct because `\rule` is indide `\textsc` which is inside `\huge`

Comment: You could also try the [`latexindent.plx` Perl script](https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.plx) on your existing LaTeX files.

Comment: You could try `filetype indent on`.

Answer (score 6):

I allways had a bad indentation with VIM, even after trying many stuff. if it helps I just turn it off and indent manual. there is the autoindent, the smartindent, and not sure if any other "geek" indent type setting just if you would like to experimentate combinations of on off

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting

also maybe trying with the :set paste could be what you need.

http://ayaz.wordpress.com/2008/06/21/paste-mode-pasting-text-and-indenting-it-in-vim/

Answer (score 0):

The default indenting for .tex files is set for plain TeX, you can set it to LaTeX adding the following line to .vimrc:

```
 let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

Comment: Still no use though. The indentation is still non-functioning. For example after an `\item`, when I want to type another `\item` on the next line, it automatically indents further two spaces.

Comment: Well turns out I perceived it falsely. If I actually type in `\item` then it will jump back the indentation.